# Different struct attribute based 32bit or 64bit

Tags: c#

Is there a way I can apply an attribute to a struct conditionally?

If the machine is **32bit** I want to apply this attribute

`[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]`

If the machine is **64bit** I want to apply this attribute

`[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]`

Or alternatively could I substitute a value within the attribute...

**32bit** (Pack = 2)

`[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]`

**64bit** (Pack = 8)

`[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]`

I tried using this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but it’s for custom attributes, not existing ones.

**Update:**

- I'd like to comile to "Any CPU"
- The attribute is for the [SHFILEOPSTRUCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and depending on the processor uses either or.
- I don't want to have to compile two versions.

Comment: Will you be compiling the program statically 64 and 32 bit, or are you using "Any CPU" and want to behave differently at runtime?

Comment: If only the `StructLayoutAttribute` class wasn't sealed. Doh!

Comment: you might be able to do this with conditional compilation directives.

Comment: BTW is "machine is 64bit" = "irrespective of my process' bitness the layout of struct must use 64 bit version" or even "irrespective of OS bitness layout of struct must use 64 bit version if CPU supports x64"? or just "based on process' bitness at run-time"?

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson I'm using "Any CPU"

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov it's based on process bitness at runtime - is the machine a 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: OK process bitness - 2 versions as proposed by @PhonicUK may be an answer. (Note: process still may be x86 on x64 OS, and OS could be x86 on machine that can support x64)

Comment: You'll have to do this the same way the .NET framework does.  Two declarations for the struct and two declarations for SHFileOperation().

Comment: @Hans Passant I found this which has the two declaratrions http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3590/C-does-Shell-Part-2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question.

The answer I first thought of was preprocessor directives and 32- and 64-bit compiled assemblies. You can use the same code, even the same project, just build and deploy it two ways depending on the target system:

```
#ifdef Bit32
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
#endif
#ifdef Bit64
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
#endif
```

This would require defining Bit32 and Bit64 compilation constants for your project based on the target architecture, and probably building your app twice.

If you want to do this at runtime, I don't think it's possible unless you emit the entire class dynamically at runtime. The attributes may only have constant data, and they cannot be conditionally applied at runtime (preprocessor directives operate at compile-time, not runtime).

The only other way I can think to do this is to copy the class definition into two namespaces, and conditionally use one or the other based on the Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem property. You can use this property to conditionally control which class you instantiate, or which strategy for creation you choose (which factory method or related pattern is used), but you can't conditionally control attributes at runtime; their information is statically compiled into the assembly manifest as metadata. This one in particular is used by the runtime itself to define how it stores the object's members as heap data, and you don't ever really look for this attribute in user code and use it to define behavior (thus ignoring or specifying a conditional Pack value at runtime).

Comment: It's fun the same way being tied up and choked in the bedroom is fun; definitely takes a certain mindset to look at it that way.

Comment: yes, I should pick my words more careful - fun as in "exciting, interesting, adventurous but unlikely profitable". I think "tied up and choked" is too grim comparison, unless of cause one decides on such approach for real production code.

Comment: could an interface be used in this case?

Comment: Yes, you could abstract both structs behind an interface, and then inject one or the other to any usage. That would eliminate the need to separate the structs by namespace; one can be MyBit64Struct and the other MyBit32Struct, and as long as all usages are of their common interface IMyStruct you get what you want. The only possible issue is that you would have to have some sort of factory to produce IMyStructs; usages couldn't `new` one up. That's easy to set up.

Answer (score 1):

Create two different build targets (one for 32 bit, one for 64 bit), add a conditional compilation symbol for each (x86 for one, x86_64 for the other) and use `#ifdef`'s around the structure definitions.

Comment: No more upvotes :(.... I think this approach would work - compile 2 versions of the same class/struct and dynamically load one at run-time depending on current process' bitness. This way you have one struct/class and can easily use it in the rest of the code without strange ifdefs.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov - should of said, I don't really want to compile two versions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. Just have 2 structures and provide a way to convert both into shared struct or class for handling...

Note: feature you are asking for is very strange (different explicit layout of structure based on type of JIT that happened at runtime). In most cases this used for physical layout of bytes that matches some well-known fixed protocol independent of application bittness. You may consider your case as having 2 different protocols/interops for x86/x64 cases and be happy with 2 structures.